# PHP - Server error 500 while processing (not uploading) big file

Tags: php, ini, http-status-code-500

I try to get an 440mb CSV file into array:

```
$handle = fopen("stuff.csv", "r");
$data = array();
while (($line = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ';')) !== FALSE)
{
    $data[] = $line;
}
```

it breaks up after about 20 seconds, in the PHP ini the `max_execution_time` is set to `50` and `memory_limit` to `1024`. What could be the trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Did you specified 1024`M` or just 1024?
2. It is **more** possible that 1024Mb is not enough.

You can:

- check out logs, for that look at `error_log` value in `php.ini`
- increase memory twice and measure time of execution - if it will increase too, it is 100% `memory_limit` issue

In the future, it is more efficient to process large files in background scripts. You can use [Gearman](http://gearman.org/) for that.

Comment: Yes I just increased to 3000mb and it worked. I shouldn't have ask too fast damnit :/